# Network Manager Gnome Wifi sharing not portable

Tags: networking, raspbian-stretch, networkmanager

I set this up succesffully using the network-manager-gnome gui to share the wifi to the ethernet (with DCHP) and it seems to work well on my Pi - I can connect and access the WAN when I have a Wifi connection,but will get an assigned IP even if I dont has an active wifi connection on the Pi.
That means I can VNC in and join a Wifi network - all good.

However when I send an SD card image to someone as part of a workflow I have created with the Pi, they cannot connect through the ethernet as I do - the DCHP sharing connection part does not allocate an address to the connected device. 
I suspect the network-manager-gnome ethernet sharing is tied to the specific mac address of the ethernet device and not just eth0.
Any idea how to make this portable?
I need the recipient of the image to have it just work when they plug it in, as they will have little to no linux experience.

I have verified that all the hardware is working their end.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `networkmanager`?

It is, of course, possible to replace `dhcpcd` (which is the default for Raspbian) with `networkmanager`, but getting support to work in the GUI is far from straightforward,.

Debian uses [predictable network interface names](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#new-interface-names) by default (these can be used in Raspbian, but are not default).

`networkmanager` normally requires configuration for each MAC and is not really portable between installations - indeed the concept of moving whole OS between systems is unusual - even if common for Raspbian users; even then [predictable network interface names](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#new-interface-names) preclude this.

Ubuntu MATE installations which use `networkmanager` are not portable between Pi systems (although it is possible to configure them to run on multiple systems).

Frankly, I think `dhcpcd` works as well as `networkmanager`, but is easier to configure.

If you want to manually configure NetworkManager it stores its configuration files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, but this is far from straightforward.

My tutorial [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
 explains how to setup networking using `dhcpcd`, but other than setting up `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` (which can be done from the GUI) little is actually needed.

Comment: I wanted to use a Gui because then the end user can use the same system to connect to Wifi (*whatever it may be for them locally) But it sounds like that is not going to work for the remote user.

I tried the DCHP route, but I didnt get it work work other than for me.Perhaps there is a clearer set of instructions than I managed to find (and I have been looking extensively)

I guess I need to figure out this portability issue somehow - so any pointers greatfully recieved.

Thanks for the clarity on networkmanager though

Comment: Ok so reading your helpful guide if I pass net.ifnames=0 in /boot/cmdline.txt, I should just be able to refer to eth0 wlan0 and not unique interface names, making it more portable? Or indeed in raspi-config (I appear to have the updated version) so predicatble names off = eth0, wlan0 on=wlanxsomething?

Comment: I managed to get the DCHP working using these instructions:
[https://www.instructables.com/id/Share-WiFi-With-Ethernet-Port-on-a-Raspberry-Pi/] 
and setting `predictable names off` in the network `raspi-config` config. Currently with the remote person, will see if it works. Thanks for the help